# EditText above listview, scroll page with keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

so i have some elements (including an EditText) above my ListView. The EditText is essentially a custom search field that I implemented to add some extra functionality to the filtering of the ListView. The EditText cannot be a header of the ListView because I don't want it to scroll off screen as you go through the list.

All works well, except on smaller devices. The screen does not scroll when you are entering text in the EditText so you can't see the live-filtering within the ListView.

Usually you would make the parent item in the layout file a ScrollView and define the activity's windowSoftInputMode as adjustResize, but this is not an option due to the fact that I have this ListView within the layout and it is a sin to have a ListView within the ScrollView.

Ideally, I'm looking for a way to make the following happen:
-upon the EditText gaining focus, I'd like it to scroll to the top of the page, and the listview occupy the rest of the screen.
-upon the EditText losing focus I'd like the screen to return to it's default state.

so far, the only real way that I'm coming up with doing this is to manually detect the keyboard showing up and then hide the top of the screen, and then upon detecting the keyboard disappearing i would show it again.

can anyone suggest something better that isn't such a hack?